# How do I remove header off extension without affected website header?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, php-5.4

I have a one page easy checkout extension for point of sale. What its doing is pulling tin the theme header. I cant hide with css as it will affect the header on the website so what is the correct way to remove this and what file will I be searching for and where would I find it.

I'm very new to magento, please remember that when responding.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the style

```
.webpos-index-index #topline { display: none; }
```

Or via the `local.xml`

```
<webpos_index_index>
   <remove="header"/>
</webpos_index_index>
```

Comment: I tried modifying the local.xml file and it affected the search feature from working in the module so I used the css and it worked perfectly. Thank you!